# Report Builder 3.0 Replace Function not working for SSRS Sharepoint Integrated Report

Tags: reporting-services, sharepoint-2013, reportbuilder3.0

I have a bar chart where the series has an action "Go To URL" to go to a detail report.
The expression for the action is:

```
="http://servername/sites/testsite/Dashboards/TestDashboard/TestDetail.aspx?SelectedMonth=" + Replace(Parameters!DateCalendarYear.Value, "&", "%26") + "&SelectedCategory=" + Replace(Fields!Category.UniqueName, "&", "%26"))
```

When I run the report in SSRS Sharepoint Integrated Mode it generates the url but does not replace the & with the encoded value %26.  I tested this on a similar report that is running on SSRS native mode and it works fine.

Does anybody know why the Replace function is not working on reports that are run in SSRS sharepoint integrated mode?

URL Generated in SSRS Native(Works Correctly):

```
http://servername/sites/testsite/Dashboards/TestDashboard/TestDetail.aspx?SelectedMonth=%5BDate%5D.%5BCalendar%20Year%5D.%5BMonth%5D.%26%5B2014%5D%26%5B4%5D&SelectedCategory=%5BCategory%5D.%5BCategory%5D.%26%5B6%5D
```

URL Generated in SSRS Sharepoint Integrated Mode (Does not work):

```
http://servername/sites/testsite/Dashboards/TestDashboard/TestDetail.aspx?SelectedMonth=%5BDate%5D.%5BCalendar%20Year%5D.%5BMonth%5D.&%5B2014%5D&%5B5%5D&SelectedCategory=%5BCategory%5D.%5BCategory%5D.&%5B3%5D
```

Comment: I think the & is a red herring - your SSRS Native URL includes multiple &. Surely it would be easier to use a Report action rather than trying to build a URL?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mike.  It would be simpler to use a Go To Report action, but in this case the users want to be able to click on a bar in the chart and be taken to another sharepoint page with various reports on it which not all might be SSRS reports.

Comment: Just moved the report to an instance of SSRS native and it works correctly, so it seems like integrated mode does not support all functions of SSRS.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was planning to open the report in a new tab anyway found a solution here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6ca4b1d4-3a04-413b-bd31-856aac3d8a8c/how-to-open-url-in-new-tab-rather-than-new-window-in-ssrs-2008-r2?forum=sqlreportingservices

When generating the url used the javascript escape function on the parameters.